# Error when trying to access elements in map

Tags: c++

Here is my .h file containing the struct I am creating.

```
struct Market{
  string file_name;
  vector<string> symbol_list={"AA","AXP","BA","BAC","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD",
                 "DIS","GE","HD","HPQ","IBM","INTC","JNJ","JPM",
                 "KFT","KO","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","PFE",
                 "PG","T","TRV","UTX","VZ","WMT","XOM"};
  map<long, vector<double>> stocks;

  Market()=default;
  Market(string s);

  double get_price(string, long) const;
  pair<double, double> high_low_year(long year, string symbol);
};

#endif
```

I am trying to create the get_price method. It will take the inputted string and be sure that it is an element of symbol_list, and find its index. I will use this index to find the corresponding element in the map called "stocks".

When I use any sort of indexing technique or the find function, I get errors. Since get_price is a const method, I have figured out I cannot use [] indexing, as this will alter the map if the key is not present. The find function is also giving me crazy errors. Here is a way I tried:

```
double Market::get_price(string stock, long date) const{
  //vector<string>::const_iterator stock_exist;
  //map<long, vector<double>>::const_iterator date_exist;
  auto stock_exist = find(symbol_list.begin(), symbol_list.end(), stock);
  auto date_exist = find(stocks.begin(), stocks.end(), date);
  if (stock_exist != symbol_list.end() and date_exist != stocks.end()){
    double stock_index = (stock_exist) - symbol_list.begin();
    double price = stocks.find(date)->second[stock_index];
    return price;
  }
  else{
    return -1.0;
  }
}
```

which yields this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:199:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const std::pair<const long int, std::vector<double> >’ and ‘const long int’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Does `auto date_exist = stocks.find(date)` work?

Answer (score 0):

You should use...

```
auto date_exist = stocks.find(date);
```

...instead of...

```
auto date_exist = find(stocks.begin(), stocks.end(), date);
```

That's because `std::map` has its own [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) member function, which will use an optimal binary search.

The `find` you tried to use - `<algorithm>`'s non-member [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) - won't do what you want: it searches for a match with the map entries' `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const long, vector<double>>` - you don't want to have to specify the expected `vector` when searching.  It's usage would look like this:

```
pair<const long, vector<double>> mypair{ 20L, {2.3, -5.1} };
auto xxx = find(stocks.begin(), stocks.end(), mypair);
...if xxx != stocks.end(), *xxx is the matching pair in stocks...
```